# DSpace: Statistics doesn't show all the periods

Tags: solr, statistics, dspace

The Statistics on JSPUI (Administrator panel) is just showing until 2014/07. Where can I find possible errors on the configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

You should generate the data from the logs using (from the /bin directory of your dspace instalation):

./dspace stat-general

./dspace stat-monthly

./dspace stat-report-general

./dspace stat-report-monthly